# change past series tradingview

Tags: series, pine-script

I'm a newbie on pine-script, what I'm trying to do is change a past series value, in particular:

```
myseries[1] = dummy
```

Can anyone tell me if it is possible? And if it is how to do it?
all the best in advance.

Comment: No, it's not possible. What is your purpose?

Comment: Thank you for you reply.  My purpose is remove a past point on a plot. Do you know any way to achieve this?

Comment: I don't think that's possible. Maybe give us more info on why you want to delete a past point and we can offer a workaround.

Comment: I have to draw a harmonic pattern. Then first of all I have to find the starting point and the second point.  Then I have to find the local maximum and minimum.

Answer (score 0):

This feature is required if you want to plot a line of type style_linebr, and want to add a break in line at the previous bar.